# Store dynamic amounts of data in a class C++

Tags: c++

I have a class that stores data and within the class I have an array called 'position' that stores strings of 2 characters. Unfortunately, the amount of 2 character strings it should hold will vary:

```
class shipStatus
{
public:
    char* name;
    int x{};
    char position[x][2];        // does not work

    void setInfo(char name[], int x);
    void displayStatus();
};
```

The setInfo function assigns a numerical value to x, which varies among objects. I would like the value of x to also dictate the length of the character array 'position'.

For example:
if x = 3 then

```
char position[3][2];  // the length of the second array is always 2
```

How can I make my code do this? If I try adding a variable as the parameters my code does not compile.
Here is my setInfo function:

```
void shipStatus::setInfo(char name[], int x)
{
    name = name;
    x = x;
}
```

Comment: In C++, we do not use char* for strings, we use std::string for strings. Best, do not use pointers at all. Additionally, do not use C-Style arrays. Use std::vector instead. This can grow dynamically

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how `std::vector`s work, and read it. You've described exactly how vectors work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm assuming a vector is like a python list?

Comment: Your problem is that `x` is not a compile time constant. However, you shouldn't be dealing with this yourself anyway; take a look at [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Should my array be of type std::string or char?

Comment: it should probably be a ````std::vector<std::string>````

Comment: *I'm assuming a vector is like a python list?* -- A `vector` is a `vector`.  Python and C++ are two different languages.  [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  Also, you shouldn't go down the road of trying to write C++ programs using python or any other language as a model.

Comment: PLZ Identify your PL: C or C++? You get different options based on your preferred PL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is C++, you should use the C++ facilities that are available to you.  In your case, it would be [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Below is an example using basically what your original `shipStatus` structure consisted of, and changing it to using the above mentioned constructs:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class shipStatus
{
    std::string name;  // <-- Replaced char*
    std::vector<std::array<char, 2>> position;  // <-- A vector of an array that has a size of 2
    public: 
        void setInfo(std::string n, int x);
        void displayStatus();
        void setPosition(size_t whichItem, char c1, char c2);  
        size_t getNumPositions() const;
};

void shipStatus::setInfo(std::string n, int x)
{
    name = n;
    position.resize(x);  // <-- All we need to do is resize() to dynamically resize the vector   
} 

void shipStatus::displayStatus()
{
   for (auto& p : position)
      std::cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << "\n";
}  

void shipStatus::setPosition(size_t whichItem, char c1, char c2)
{
     position[whichItem] = {c1, c2};  // <-- we set one item in the vector, and in 
                                      //     that item, we set the [0] and [1] characters  
}

size_t shipStatus::getNumPositions() const { return position.size(); }

int main()
{
    shipStatus sStatus;
    sStatus.setInfo("Ship 1", 3);
    sStatus.setPosition(0, '4', '2');
    sStatus.setPosition(1, 'a', 'b');
    sStatus.setPosition(2, 'y', 'z');
    std::cout << "Number of positions: " << sStatus.getNumPositions() << "\n";
    sStatus.displayStatus();
}
```

Output:

```
Number of positions: 3
4 2
a b
y z
```

Note that we no longer need `x` as a member, since a `std::vector` knows its size already by calling the `size()` member function.

Answer (score 0):

```
char **position;
position = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*x);
for (int i=0; i<x; ++i)
{
    position[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
}
```

This is a classic "C" way of doing it, will work in C++ too.
For a cleaner approach, we should use vectors/lists for this purpose.